# How to add a record to an access database - visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I made a quiz which should store the users high score in a database however I keep getting an error satying  'Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString'

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Pure

Dim pro As String
Dim connstring As String
Dim command As String
Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
```

And here is the rest of the code which is supposed to add the highscore to the access database

```
Private Sub btnSummary_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSummary.Click
        pro = "provider=microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=flashcard login.accdb" 'Establish connection with database
        connstring = pro
        myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
        myconnection.Open() 'Open connection
        If lblScore11.Text > lblHighScore.Text Then 'If current socre is greater than high score
            lblScore11.Text = lblHighScore.Text
            command = " insert into results ([score]) values ('" & lblHighScore.Text & "')"
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(command, myconnection) 'Establish connection
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("score", CType(lblHighScore.Text, String)))
        End If
    End Sub
```

I added this try-catch statement at the end (Inside the if statement)

```
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myconnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: Based on your error, it sounds like myconnection is already open.  Always close your database connections after using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other issues, but the big one is you actually need to run the query:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Also, this query is still crazy-vulnerable to injection issues. This kind of string substitution is **NEVER** okay for an SQL string:

```
 values ('" & lblHighScore.Text & "')"
```

Here's a full re-write with better patterns:

```
Dim connString As String = "provider=microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=flashcard login.accdb" 

Private Sub btnSummary_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSummary.Click

    If lblScore11.Text <= lblHighScore.Text Then Return
    lblHighScore.Text = lblScore11.Text

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connSstring), _
          cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO results ([score]) VALUES (?)", conn)
        'Use the actual OleDbType that maps to the database column and length here
        cmd.Parameters.Add("score", OleDbType.LongVarWChar).Value = lblScore11.Text
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```